# Biztalk slow processing of items in batch

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

We have a process where in items are being drop in BizTalk by batch, we just noticed that in our prod environment 1 batch will be processed 1 at a time (1 item after another) where in in our development processing is equals to 1 batch to many process(hope you know what i mean). Configuration in dev and prod are identical but db data in prod are huge compared to dev. What can we check that is causing this?

Thanks in advance

NewbieDeveloper

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific?  What does "1 batch to many process" mean?  Ochestrations?  Send Ports?  Also, can you give an idea of the size of the batches involved?  Are they different between PROD and DEV?

Comment: it means orchestration, the configuration of dev and prod are the same but the created orchestrations are different thus making the dev processing of files faster

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be hitting some throttling. You need to monitor the [Host Throttling Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx) using perfmon.